# Can't establish ssh connection: "debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory" and "Host key verification failed."

Tags: ssh

I'm not able to establish an ssh connection to one of my remote servers.

I have the address, username and password for both.

To create the ssh connections as follow `ssh user@server` which gives me the following error `Host key verification failed.`

The most common answer to this topic is to run `ssh-keygen -R hostname`. The problem is on my remote server I have very limited rights and it gives me the error `ssh-keygen: command is not found`. Usually commands like `service` or `su` all give me the same error `command is not found`.

Since I'm able to create a connection over SFTP with Filezilla, can I manually fix this is problem? Also, if it's important, my `.ssh` directory is empty, so there is no `known_host` or something like this.

Here is the full output of `ssh -v user@server`

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Connecting to XXX port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1Debian-5+deb8u4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA XXX
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

I use my Windows PC which connects to a remote server over `ssh` (let's call it Server 1) with PuTTy. On server 1 I have nearly zero rights to run anything besides `scp` and `ssh` and basic shell commands. On this server, I run a webshop which backups should stall on an other server (lets call it Server 2).

I wish I could use `sftp`, but I can't use it and can't install it on server 1. So I have to go with `scp`. I tried it with `curl sftp://xxx.xxx` which to my surprise did work, but still gets me an new error `curl: (51) SSL peer certificcate or SSH remote key was not ok`.

Answer (score 36):

The `Host key verification failed` error message means that your SSH client has compared the received public key of the remote server and noticed that it does not match the stored version of the host key in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

The command `ssh-keygen -R hostname` does not do anything to the remote host and does not require any special permissions: all it does is remove the old host key for `hostname` from *your local* `known_hosts` file. Then, the next time you connect to `hostname`, your SSH client will display the fingerprint of `hostname`'s current host key and will prompt you to accept it. Just like when connecting to some host for the first time.

But if you don't have that command available, you could try connecting with

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server
```

The default value for the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option is `ask`, which prompts you to accept or reject previously-unknown host keys... but since your session apparently has no pseudo-TTY, the `ssh` client is in non-interactive mode and won't prompt. The value `no` should auto-accept the host key: if possible, `ssh` will write the host key to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. If this is successful, you'll need to use the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option only when connecting to a particular server for the first time.

Comment: After i tried it with `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server` i got an new error `Permission denied (publickey, password).` After that i switched to `.ssh/` and the file `known_hosts` got created. In the following i tried the normal `ssh user@server` and got the error `ssh: connect to host server port 22: connection refused`

Comment: OK, so it looks like you got through the host key check now, but failed authentication... and on the second time the server just rejected the connection attempt. Because you don't seem to have a /dev/tty device node, the SSH client thinks it won't be able to ask for passwords securely. You really should contact the administrator of the first server: this is probably an error in the setup of your restricted chroot environment.

Comment: Glad it wasnt my fault all the way. I will get in contact with the administrator of the first server (we rent a sever at an webhost). I will keep you updatet if i got some new informations.

Comment: @sHamann : so what happened after that ??

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, with bitbucket.org :-o They just changed their type of keys, all seems config seems okay at my side.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when trying to SSH to remote machine from host running a custom built buildroot rootfs.

What I observed is the error message echoed "Host Key Verification failed" is misleading for scenario I faced. It was not actually about known_hosts file but regarding a echo that ssh want to do (like below)

> This key is not known by any other names
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

And for that it needs /dev/tty, which it is unable to find/write hence the error

> read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory

So we need to fix this so that we can key in "yes" in console thereafter ssh can add the host key to known_hosts.

Solution which worked for me is, remove /dev/tty and softlink current tty to it.

```
console=`tty`
ln -s $console /dev/tty
```